# Regexp for single quote replacement in SQL statment

Tags: javascript, sql-server, regex

I have googled this ane are really surprised not to find a ready made solution to this as I believe that it is a problem that is faced by anyone who is updating databases from forms.

Problem is the single quote that is used in text fields as an apostrophe and other instances.

So I need to find are replace all occurrences of single quotes within an SQL statement in Javascript / Nodejs before sending it to the database, this of course is not a hard-coded statement and it will be different every time, but the following includes carriage returns in the sql statement as well as spaces before and after an equal sign as well as no spaces to try and catch all occurrences.

The key thing really is the "=" followed by a single speech mark, the text to grab and the closing single speech mark followed by a space, a comma, or the word "WHERE".

I am no expert with regex, but have come up with this, which only correctly extracts a couple of the strings:

```
/\= *'(.*)' *[, *]/g
```

Would appreciate help from any of the regex experts out there :-)

```
update XXX set status = 'Pending's' where xx = 'xxx'
UPDATE XX_XXX

SET

SUBJECT='Test of system's', SERIAL_NUMBER='SN'1'23', SPEC='Verify order's package is complete',

DESCRIPTION='13.3/8'' Buttress Pin's ' WHERE ID='1002-15'
```

This should be the result:

```
update XXX set status = 'Pending''s' where xx = 'xxx'
UPDATE XX_XXX

SET

SUBJECT='Test of system''s', SERIAL_NUMBER='SN''1''23', SPEC='Verify order''s package is complete',

DESCRIPTION='13.3/8''' Buttress Pin''s ' WHERE ID='1002-15'
```

And these are the strings that need to be selected:

```
Pending's
Test of system's
SN'1'23
Verify order's package is complete
13.3/8'
1002-15
```

Comment: This is using regexp before sending to MS SQL, in Javascript

Comment: If you just want to create a legal SQL statement, use two single quotes: `update XXX set status = 'Pending''s'`

Comment: No. it is really a REGEXP question, does not really matter whether it is regexp in javascript or any other language, although I agree that the syntax does vary a bit

Comment: Well it does matter which language it is, because T-SQL does not support RegEx.

Comment: I can't globally replace single quotes with 2 single quotes as this: 'xxx'xx' will become ''xxx''xxx'' and it should be 'xxx''xxx'. it is only the text contained within the outer quotes that needs to be replkaced.

Comment: @crankshaft Should `13.3/8'' ` really become `13.3/8''' `?

Answer (score -1):

It is very common issue, do not need regex. Just simply replace a single quote in a string to double single quote.

This is example. Just see the comment

```
--This is double quote I used, because ally's wonderland not work at here.
DECLARE @StringValueWithSingleQuote varchar( 50) =  'Ally''s wonderland'

-- just see the magid, replace double single quote to single quote while displaing
select @StringValueWithSingleQuote  

--This is actual you have to do
select REPLACE( @StringValueWithSingleQuote , char(39) , Char(39)+Char(39) )
```